# Jquery event delegation not triggering

Tags: jquery

I have put together the following JSfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/f5ytcova/

```
<div class="delFile">Delete</div>   

var are_you_sure = $('<span class="alert alert-danger">Are you sure you wish to remove this file? <span class="yes">Yes</span> | <span class="no">No</span></span>');

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delFile').css('cursor','pointer').off('click').on('click',deleteFile);
})

function deleteFile(e){
    df = $(this);
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(df).append(are_you_sure);

    // Gary - I have NO idea why this isn't working??
    $('.delFile').on('click','.no', function() {
    alert('clicked');
        $(this).parent().remove();
    })
}
```

As you'll see I basically want to dynamically remove the parent and have configured it to use Event delegation as per answers elsewhere on Stack Overflow. But for some reason, even with this configured the parent element isn't removed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you setting up an event handler (the delegated one) within an event handler (`deleteFile`)? That's almost always an antipattern. Also note that there's no need for `.off('click')` in your `ready` handler unless you really have other code that runs before ready that would have added a click handler.

Comment: The off click is because it can be called repeatedly

Comment: No, it can't. :-) jQuery calls the function you pass `ready` exactly once.

Comment: You're using event delegation inside of an event handler, which makes no sense. The whole point of using event delegation is so that you don't need to conditionally add the event handler; it's just there, waiting to be called, if and when the element exists. Any conditions necessary can be controlled by flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is:

- click on delFile
- adds yes/no
- click on No
- runs .no code and removes the element from the DOM (but not from the variable `are_you_sure`)
- *then* runs delFile click again and re-adds the jquery element that you've just removed

Add a `return false` or, more specifically, [`event.stopImmediatePropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) to your inner (.no) click handler

```
$('.delFile').on('click','.no', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    // stop the `.delFile` element getting a click
    return false;
})
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0nfpox35/

---

Note that with your original code you don't need event delegation because you add the HTML directly before the event handler.  You're also appending a jquery object which complicates things.

The delegated event handler can be outside the click handler, which is what event delegation is for:

```
function deleteFile(e){
    df = $(this);
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(df).append(are_you_sure);
}

$('.delFile').on('click','.no', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
})
```

Comment: Thank you - this was literally a copy/paste answer

Answer (score 0):

You're repeatedly adding listeners and adding and removing the `.alert` element, since `deleteFile` fires not only when `delete` is pressed, but also when the appended element (eg `.no`) is pressed.

I'd attach a listener to remove the parent `are_you_sure` element instead, and inside `deleteFile`, make sure that the clicked element isn't a child of the `.alert` before appending the `.alert`.

You'll also want to use `.detach` instead of `.remove` to preserve the `no` event listener across multiple `delete` clicks.

```js
var are_you_sure = $('<span class="alert alert-danger">Are you sure you wish to remove this file? <span class="yes">Yes</span> | <span class="no">No</span></span>')
  .on('click', '.no', function() {
    $(this).parent().detach();
  });

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delFile').css('cursor','pointer').on('click', deleteFile);
})

function deleteFile(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  if (!e.target.closest('.alert')) {
    // Then the click was on the outer "Delete" text node, not the .alert section
      $(this).append(are_you_sure);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="delFile">
Delete
</div>
```